# Invalid date when submitting Google XML sitemap

Tags: php

When validating my [XML sitemap](http://www.moto-trek.co.uk/sitemap/xml), google says:

*Invalid date
An invalid date was found. Please fix the date or formatting before resubmitting.*

I convert the mysql timestamp by:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($row['modified']['value']))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 'lastmod' element has to be of the format `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD` so use:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['modified']['value']))
```

or

```
gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+00:00', strtotime($row['modified']['value']))
```

[Read more here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71936#lastmod)

Comment: Those trying to translate this PHP solution to Java should note, that the ":" in 00:00 is really critical, and is missing from the standard formatting utility.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [the `DATE_W3C` date format constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.w3c), which matches [the required format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

```php
gmdate(DATE_W3C, strtotime($row['modified']['value']));
```